# Difficulties to understand np.nditer

Tags: python

I am very new to python. I want to clearly understand the below code, if there's anyone who can help me.

Code:
import numpy as np

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4,99,11,22], [5, 6, 7, 8,43,54,22]])

for x in np.nditer(arr[0:,::4]):

  print(x)
```

My understanding:

1. This 2D array has two 1D arrays.
2. np.nditer(arr[0:,::4]) will give all value from 0 indexed array to upto last array, ::4 means the gap between printed arrays will be 4.

Question:

1. Is my understanding for no 2 above correct?
2. How can I get the **index** for the print(x)? Because of the step difference of 4 e.g [0:,::4] or any gap [0:,::x] I want to find out the exact index that it is printing. But how?

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your questions below

1. Yes, I think your understanding is correct. It might help to first print what `arr[0:,::4]` returns though:

```
iter_array = arr[0:,::4]
print(iter_array)
>>> [[ 1 99]
>>>  [ 5 43]]
```

The slicing takes out each 4th index of the original array. All `nditer` does is iterate through these values in order. (Quick FYI: `arr[0:]` and `arr[:]` are equivalent, since the starting point is 0 by default).

2. As you pointed out, to get the index for these you need to keep track of the slicing that you did, i.e. `arr[0:, ::x]`. Remember, `nditer` has nothing to do with how you sliced your array. I'm not sure how to best get the indices of your slicing, but this is what I came up with:

```
import numpy as np

ls = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4,99,11,22],
    [5, 6, 7, 8,43,54,22]
]

arr = np.array(ls)
inds = np.array([
    [(ctr1, ctr2) for ctr2, _ in enumerate(l)] for ctr1, l in enumerate(ls)
]) # create duplicate of arr filled with zeros

step = 4
iter_array = arr[0:,::step]
iter_inds = inds[0:,::step]

print(iter_array)
>>> [[ 1 99]
>>>  [ 5 43]]
print(iter_inds)
>>> [[[0 0]
>>>   [0 4]]
>>> 
>>>  [[1 0]
>>>   [1 4]]]
```

All that I added here was an `inds` array. This array has elements equal to their own index. Then, when you slice both arrays in the same way, you get your indices. Hopefully this helps!